# How do I track the position of a moving svg element in relationship to a fixed svg element?

Tags: javascript, svg, position

I am working on a project that moves elements of an svg file up and down across a horizontal line.  I want to track the position of the moving element in relation to the fixed line.  Both elements are within the same svg.  I tried using

```
getBoundingClientRect().top
```

However, this does not provide a good solution as the coordinates produced by the getBoundingClientRect() function change based on the size, position, and zoom, of the viewport.  It is not the same for every device in every situation.  I need to be able to know when a specific path is a certain distance above or below a fixed line.  I'm using setAttribute('transform','translate()) on the containing group to move a group of objects in my project.  I need to know the position of an individual object within my group in relation to a fixed line not in my group.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="ex1-3rds-quarter-s" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
 y="0px" width="323.333px" height="55.333px" viewBox="0 0 323.333 55.333" enable-background="new 0 0 323.333 55.333"
 xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="ledgerlines">
    <line id="MidCLine1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="48.09" y1="41.694" x2="57.924" y2="41.694"/>
  </g>
  <g id="note1">
    <path class="root" d="M54.113,38.945c1.116,0,2.172,0.578,2.172,1.813c0,1.435-1.116,2.411-2.052,2.969c-0.717,0.418-1.514,0.717-2.331,0.717
            c-1.116,0-2.172-0.578-2.172-1.813c0-1.435,1.116-2.411,2.052-2.969C52.499,39.244,53.296,38.945,54.113,38.945z"/>
    <path d="M54.113,33.963c1.116,0,2.172,0.578,2.172,1.813c0,1.435-1.116,2.411-2.052,2.969c-0.717,0.418-1.514,0.717-2.331,0.717
            c-1.116,0-2.172-0.578-2.172-1.813c0-1.435,1.116-2.411,2.052-2.969C52.499,34.262,53.296,33.963,54.113,33.963z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to track the position of the path without using the getBoundingClientRect() function?

Thanks,
--christopher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing your path in an svg 'wrapper/empty' element. Then use `getBBox()` for the wrapper. This will provide x,y values  used to set/read the path's translations.

EDIT: I have included an example below that can move rects between reference lines. This works even when the rect has been previously transformed. This uses a single SVG Wrapper. Note: If you are only going to transform your element a single time, then you do not have to use the matrix transform on the bbx, bby values. they can be used directly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <title>SVG Wrapper</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body style='font-family:arial'>
            <center>
            <h4>SVG Wrapper</h4>
            <div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
           Translate rects to line via SVG Wrapper. Can translate between lines
            </div>
            <div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:gainsboro;width:400px;height:400px;'>
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400">
<line id=refLine1 stroke='blue' stroke-width='2' x1=20 y1=40 x2=380 y2=40 />
<line id=refLine2 stroke='maroon' stroke-width='2' x1=20 y1=100 x2=380 y2=100 />
<g id=rectG>
<rect id=redRect fill=red x=60 y=200 width=100 height=50 />
<rect id=greenRect fill=lime x=260 y=320 width=100 height=50 />
</g>
<svg id=Wrapper />
</svg>
            </div>
<center>
<button onClick=moveToLine(refLine1,redRect)>Move Red Rect to <span style=color:blue>Line 1</span></button>
<button onClick=moveToLine(refLine1,greenRect)>Move Green Rect to <span style=color:blue>Line 1</span></button>
<br />
<button onClick=moveToLine(refLine2,redRect)>Move Red Rect to <span style=color:maroon>Line 2</span></button>
<button onClick=moveToLine(refLine2,greenRect)>Move Green Rect to <span style=color:maroon>Line 2</span></button>
</center>
            <br />SVG Source:<br />
            <textarea id=svgSourceValue style='font-size:110%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:200px'></textarea>
            <br />Javascript:<br />
            <textarea id=jsValue style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
            </center>
            <div id='browserDiv' style='padding:5px;position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;background-color:gainsboro;'>OK in:IE11/CH32/FF28<br /></div>
<script id=myScript>
function moveToLine(refLine,rect)
{
    //---move rect to this location at line---
    var targetY=refLine.y1.baseVal.value
    var targetX=rect.x.baseVal.value
    Wrapper.appendChild(rect)
    var bb=Wrapper.getBBox()
    //---return rect to its <g>---
    rectG.appendChild(rect)
    var bbx=bb.x
    var bby=bb.y

    //---bind wrapper x,y to rect's current transform--
    var pnt = mySVG.createSVGPoint();
    pnt.x = bbx;
    pnt.y = bby;
    var sCTM = rect.getCTM();
    PNT = pnt.matrixTransform(sCTM.inverse());
    //---translate rect's x,y to target---
    var transX=targetX-PNT.x
    var transY=targetY-PNT.y

    rect.setAttribute("transform","translate("+transX+" "+transY+")")

    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}

</script>
            <script>
            document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
            function init()
            {
                svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
                jsValue.value=myScript.text
            }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I would need to put an svg wrapper around each element I want to track?

Comment: You can have a single wrapper that is filled by the path you want to read or postion. I'll add an example to this answer. Give me about an hour...

Comment: Thank you, Francis.  There are many new things here of which I am not yet familiar.  I will chew on this for a couple of days to try to really understand it well and see if something like this can be incorporated into what I have written already.

Comment: Francis, thank you again.  This has helped immensely.

Comment: OK, great. Good luck with your app.

Comment: Francis,  When I view your example, it works great.  However, when I try to incorporate a wrapper into my code, the script stops working.  I've tried  the 'Wrapper.appendChild("MidCLine1");' similar to what you have in your code as well as 'document.getElementById("Wrapper").appendChild("MidLine1")'.  Internet Explorer throws a hierarchy request error.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  --thanks

Comment: Could you post your code in your question? I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you.  Here is a link to my project.  I have commented out the portion of your code which gave me errors.  I have the vertical positioning working.  However, the horizontal positioning is way off.  You can see the lines appear as you click the left arrow. [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zliipnkzk2mnbl/test.html

Comment: What is weird is that some of my lines are correct while some are shifted left and others are shifted right.

Comment: Try removing the quote marks,  so changes are: Wrapper.appendChild(MidCLine1); and ledgerlines.appendChild(MidCLine1);

Comment: I note that you use getElementById when you may not need to. Once an element is placed in the DOM, with an id, it becomes a valid object call by using its id directly.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I have taken the quotes out and the code compiles with no errors, but now some of the lines are not being displayed and very few are center aligned to the center of the note.  Does the additional use of the getElementById cause problems?  I am still mostly brand new to javascript.  Sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: the getElementById will not cause a problem. Try changing the width to 400 so you do not loose visibility of the lines at the end of the scale. I'm not a musical person, so I can't determine how the notes are supposed to be aligned.

Comment: I'm not sure why I am so dumb.  I did get it working though not with the wrapper or with the use of the sCTM function.  I'm still a bit clueless as to how to use those screen coordinate functions.  I removed a small thing in how I was calculating the horizontal center. The whole thing works great now.   Thank you for all your help.  Should I check your answer now that my question is resolved?

Comment: Very glad to see you have solved your problem. I'm sure you will not have any problem learning to use svg + Javascript. Yes, I would appreciate a check...thanks