# tracking position of a circle moving in a straight line

Tags: javascript, svg, position

A circle moves along a line. I need to find its x and y coordinates and perform some tasks if the circle has reached a desired position. all SVG elements are created dynamically and are placed within same SVG tag. i found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23522654/4586638) but i couldn't follow it. Is there any simpler way of getting its x and y position?

```
function RunTrain(x,y,desti,dur,r,begin)
 {
    var xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var C=document.createElementNS(xmlns,"circle");
    C.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",x);
    C.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",y);
    C.setAttributeNS(null,"r",r);
    C.setAttribute("style","stroke-width:1;stroke:blue;fill:skyblue");

    var animate=document.createElementNS(xmlns,"animate");
    animate.setAttribute("attributeName","cx");
    animate.setAttribute("attributeType","XML");
    animate.setAttribute("from",x);
    animate.setAttribute("to",desti);
    animate.setAttribute("dur",dur);
    animate.setAttribute("begin","indefinite");
    animate.setAttribute("repeatCount","1");
    animate.setAttribute("fill","freeze");

    C.appendChild(animate);
    document.getElementById("id1").appendChild(C);//id1 is id of svg
    animate.beginElement();
 }
```

Comment: You can access the current animated value of the `cx` attribute by using `C.cx.animVal.value`.

Comment: @Paul LeBeau what if i want to do find the value outside this function where c has no existence?

Comment: Give the circle an `id` and then get a reference to it later with `var C = document.getElementById("myCircleId");`.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau thanks a lot. it works perfectly